# Regarding finding the event when clicked on column menu

Tags: angular, typescript, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I’m using AGGrid enterprise and recently I encountered an issue **in angular** that when I choose reset columns in column menu of the grid, the
*setColumnVisible false in one column* the hidden column is shown when grid gets reset.

Please see below images to know more about the issue refer image name for pictures:

1. I have set column visibility to false for `repName` column:

---

[image]

2. In colDefs:

---

[image]

3. Clicking on reset columns in column menu:

---

[image]

4. The hidden column poped up:

---

[image]

I have read many websites and documentation to solve this issue but that didn’t worked also the documentation only mentioned about how to reposition, rearrange and redesign the column menu but what if I want the change the functionality of default column menu option globally in two thousands pages?

I can create custom column menu but I’m curious weather or not AGGrid provides a way to customize the functionality of column menu options like im my case I want **Reset Columns** option to check the visibility of a particular column based on some logic.

Thank you for reading this far and thanks in advance if you tried or provided the exact solution im looking for.

```
Note: If anyone want i can replicate the problem in stackblitz or in plucker.
```

I have read many websites and documentation to solve this issue but that didn’t worked also, Hoping for solution or help.

Comment: You should probably report this in zendesk since it seems like actual bug 
https://ag-grid.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/requests/new

Comment: I have reprted this issue actually in zendesk, but i thought it will be good for others who have encountered the same issue and who are looking for the solution on stackoverflow.